# What is *:* in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I was trying to understand a Vue code when I saw something like this

```
  <q-field
      v-if="isEditing"
      :label="to.label"
      :helper="helper"
```

Can someone explain me what does this`:label="to.label"` mean in VueJS

Answer (score 3):

If you want to bind any dynamic behaviour, we need to use 'v-' prefix. in shorthand we can use ':'

full syntax
v-bind:href="url"

shorthand
:href="url"

refer: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html

Answer (score 0):

In vuejs documentation you can read how to bind props , here is the full explanation about this :
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Simply if I want to bind prop from parent component to child , I can use :name_of_prop="value_of_prop"

This ':' are short hand from v-bind :)

Answer (score 0):

As is mentioned above it is equivalent to the v-bind:

May also help to mention that anything you write inside of the quotes

```
:label="in here"
```

will be read dynamically. So for the code you were looking at `to.label` and helper are most likely values defined elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

:label="to.label is equal,

- Binding dynamic value v-bind:label="your_dynamic_value".
- Label is a props from q-field component.